# How to use Ext-designer to create UI for multiple pages?

Tags: extjs4, extjs, ext-designer

In the example section in extjs4 official site, the source code is clean and direct (on a single page). However the ext designer uses MVC architecture that I am quite confused.
If I want to create UI using extjs 4, for multiple page, am I supposed to create multiple projects in ext designer?

Answer (score 0):

I think these are two seperate questions '1. should I use MVC' and '2. Why does Designer NOT use MVC'.

In my opinion that answer to 1. should be 'yes' unless you project is relatively small and you feel comfy managing the entire codebase in one long file. This quickly becomes unmanagable and there is a lot of searching needed to locate the section you're after.

The answer to 2. is that designer is aimed to provide designers (funnily enough!) who often won't have any coding experience the ability to create prototypes and templates that developers can pick apart and build into applications. At least that was true with designer version 1. 
I believe designer 2 is aimed much much at being able to directly port code into applications but if you're talking about version 1 I think you will need to take the code generated by the designer and move it into an MVC style structure in order to build applications which are anything more than a couple of simple pages.

Comment: Great thanks for sharing your view. I do know why the MVC is introduced and when to use MVC structure. However, I thought the ext designer can help me make my single basic page (a form) and another page (a grid) in a few steps (as the example code is short and clean (non-MVC). By the way, I think the ext designer does increase the efficiency when developing a single page, complex, ajax application.